# Pie chart with three fields in Ms Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-charts

I want to make three field pie chart with label name and three colors. But i am not able to do.

What I have tried :

- Select all fields
- Insert -> pie chart

But this does not work at all :(

This is my sample data :

```
year    test2   test3
2010    20     25000
2011    100    81000
2012    1      17000
2013    1      22000
2014    2      11000
2015    1      12000
2016    2      20000
2017    3      30000
```

Please help :)

Comment: Pie charts only have one axis.  They take one column of labels and one column of values.  Can you post an example of what you're expecting it to look like?

Comment: like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9seJ.jpg  (I guess *techically* a pie chart could be drawn with multiple datasets, but not with Excel

Comment: Ohh that i don't know actually. Thanks for replying. Then can you suggest which chart is for this purpose?

Comment: Yes i want to make a pie chart as your given image.. Can it possible with excel?

Comment: Ok i will try and let you know

Comment: You might be able to show the years as follows: https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/using_pie_charts_and_doughnut_charts_in_excel.html but not the full requirement I think you are after.

Comment: No i am not getting the exact chart as your image in recommended charts tab. Can you please give a proper answer with this..would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Qharr thanks! But i want to show values not only percentage. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: pie chart are proportion based but you can edit series to show values and/or percentage.

Comment: @Qharr ok i will try thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand corrected: you actually *can* make a "**multi-level pie chart**" in Excel:

[image: multi level pie]

Here are instructions from [BrainBell](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ms-office/excel/Create_Two_Sets_Of_Slices_In_One_Pie_Chart.htm).

---

Apparently it can be a little tricky. I've never seen multi-axis pie chart before, but some of them and kinda neat..

These ones ***can't*** be easily created by Excel, but may be possible with plugins with Javascript:

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   <sup>(Click images for source page)</sup>

...and while we're looking at pretty, round data:

> [image] 
>   [image] 
>   [image]
>
> <sup>Click images for source pages)</sup>

Comment: When and when NOT to use pie charts is explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mkVPfupPidQ

Comment: @teylyn Thanks for sharing but I disagree with the lady in the video, plus she doesn't *explain *why** she feels that *"Microsoft made a mistake"* in allow Pie as a choice for that data.  I'd also like to see an explanation of how she's planning on having Microsoft changes that for her, lol.

Comment: I only had ten minutes for the video, so there's only so much that I could put in. If you are interested in more detail of the "Why", I strongly suggest you read Stephen Few's books "Show me the Numbers" and "Now You See It".  You could start with his article [Save the Pies for Dessert](https://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/save_the_pies_for_dessert.pdf). The MVP Summit, during which I recorded this video, is one of the opportunities where Microsoft listens to feedback, and MVPs have influenced many aspects of how Excel works.